# Ingress routing rules to access opentelemetry otel collector

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-nginx, open-telemetry-collector

I have setup opentelemetry otel collector on AKS cluster and used node port service to expose the endpoint running on port 5555 of the otel collector,
[image]

This setup works as expected, I am able to hit the http://{AKS_Node_IP}:30807.

Now I want to expose this url using Nginx Ingress. I did setup of nginx ingress controller using load balancer as service type and it is able to run successfully,
[image]

[image]

Now I want to ad an Ingress resource that accepts a Prefix and redicts back to the otel-collector-external service. For that I am using the following yaml,

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: obs-dev-ingress-otlp
spec:
  ingressClassName: default
  rules:
  - host: dev-obs-k8.he.net
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /otel-collector
        backend:
          service:
            name: otel-collector-external
            port:
              number: 5555
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

**NOTE** - I am using 5555 port as my reciever grpc.
Now If I try to hit the url http://{My_Load_Balancer_external_IP}/otel-collector. Nothing happens, the request is not reaching the mentioned service otel-collector-external due to which the request is not reaching the underlying pod.

I wanted to ask is there any different path that we need to expose otel-collector?

**NOTE** - I have exposed other services on the same Ingress controller and it works as expected, only otel-collector is not working.

Comment: Hi @Narinder, did you find a solution for this? I am also trying to get the ingress work for the otel-collector. Did you also try to listen on HTTP endpoint in otel-collector btw?